# Bash Add elements to an array does not work

Tags: arrays, bash

I am trying to create a Json with the IPs and macs of current Linux machine. I am doing it by creating an array with mac and Ip Address and then write a Json.

The issue is that when I access to the array the array is empty.

The code I wrote is the following:

```
    array=()
regex="\w{4}\/\w{5}\s([0-9:a-f]+)\s\w{3}\s[0-9:a-f]+\s+\w{4}\s([0-9.]+)"
ip addr show |tr -d '\n'| grep -Eo "$regex" | while read line; do item=`echo "$line" | sed -nr "s/$regex/\1 \2/p"`;echo $item; array+=${!item}; done
```

Comment: the while loop is executed in another process (subshell), because of `|`, and doesn't change caller shell

Comment: The `while` loop is in a pipeline, and therefore runs in a subshell. Use `while read ... done < <(ip addr show |tr -d '\n'| grep -Eo "$regex")` to keep the loop in the main shell.

Comment: Thanks is solved!